# get text from jqgrid cell value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have inserted an image and text in jqgrid cells using a formatter as follows:

```
function myFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{  
      switch(cellvalue){
        case 'Unknown':         newCell="<img src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break;//unknown
        case 'Informational' :  newCell="<img src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break; //informational
        case 'Warning' :        newCell="<img src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break; //warning       
        }                 
    return newCell;
}
```

I need to check each value of my cell for another operation.So I need to get only the text part of the cell value.

Something like this:

```
var rows =myGrid.getRowData();
//for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++)
for(var i=1;i<=rows.length;i++)
{
        var rowdata =myGrid.getRowData(i);
        var Val = rowdata.myColumn;    

        switch(Val){
        case 'Unknown':         do this 1;break;//unknown
        case 'Informational' :  do THIS 2;break; //informational
        case 'Warning' :        do this 3;break; //warning    
}
```

The `Val` obtained is the `image` but my requirement is the text .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add a **title** and **id** to the image in the formatter like below:

something like this :

```
<img id='cusmFrmt_"+rowObject.id+"' title='"+cellvalue+"'
src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;
```

> So formatter would be:

```
function myFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{  
          switch(cellvalue){
            case 'Unknown':         newCell="<img id='cusmFrmt_"+rowObject.id+"' title='"+cellvalue+"' src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break;//unknown
            case 'Informational' :  newCell="<img id='cusmFrmt_"+rowObject.id+"' title='"+cellvalue+"' src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break; //informational
            case 'Warning' :        newCell="<img id='cusmFrmt_"+rowObject.id+"' title='"+cellvalue+"' src='../../Content/images/ui-flag_green.png' />"+cellvalue;break; //warning       
            }                 
        return newCell;
}
```

> After that in your getRow stuff:

```
var imgObject = $('#cusmFrmt_'+rowdata.id);
// get cell value
var cellValueTxt = imgObject.attr('title');
```

So actually it will look like this:

```
var rows =myGrid.getRowData();
//for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++)
for(var i=1;i<=rows.length;i++)
{
        var rowdata =myGrid.getRowData(i);
        var Val = rowdata.myColumn;  
        // get image object     
        var imgObject = $('#cusmFrmt_'+rowdata.id);
        // get cell value
        var cellValueTxt = imgObject.attr('title');

        switch(cellValueTxt){
        case 'Unknown':         do this 1;break;//unknown
        case 'Informational' :  do THIS 2;break; //informational
        case 'Warning' :        do this 3;break; //warning    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add another column to the colModel and set either the xmlmap or jsonmap property, http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data,
then you can just reference that new column to get your value.

```
{name:'myColumnVal', hidden:true, jsonmap:'myColumn'}

var rows =myGrid.getRowData();
//for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++)
for(var i=1;i<=rows.length;i++)
{
        var rowdata =myGrid.getRowData(i);
        var Val = rowdata.myColumnVal;    

}
```